# Some confusion on using IHandleMessages

Tags: nservicebus

I have a subscriber that subscribes to multiple different publishers.  All of these publishers post a message whose interface derives from a base interfaces.  This base message contains some common attributes that all the messages require and is a marker.

```
public interface IBaseMessage : IMessage
{}

public inteface IPublisher1Message : IBaseMessage
{}

public inteface IPublisher2Message : IBaseMessage
{}
```

In the subscriber I have created a class that subscribes to all publishers in the system.

```
public BaseMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<IBaseMessage>
{
  public void Handle(IBaseMessage message) {}
}
```

I would like this to Handle the message from all publishers, but I have seen it fire for at most one publisher depending on how I do my message endpoint mappings.

```
<MessageEndpointMappings>
 <add Messages="Messages.IPublisher1Messages,Messages" Endpoint="Publisher1" />
  <add Messages="Messages.IPublisher2Messages,Messages" Endpoint="Publisher2" />
</MessageEndpointMappings>
```

Is there a way to handle messages from different publishers in one Handler?

Comment: Your config appears to be correct except for I would reference the entire assembly in the mapping instead of each specific type.  This will then scan for all types in the assembly.  You will need to have a mapping for each Publisher endpoint.

Comment: Adam, It barfed when I did that because you can't have two different publishers for the same set of messages.  I have all my messages in one assembly.

Comment: Good to know, per the post below, looks like this may not work without manually subscribing to everything.  To do that you need to take over the initialization and set the .DoNotAutoSubscribe().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you relying on auto-subscribe for this one?

Because I think I can recall having had some kind of trouble similar to yours - as I remember it, the solution was to manually subscribe to each message.

You can still rely on polymorphic message dispatch, it's just polymorphic auto-subscription that seems not to work.

Comment: This seemed to work but I had to subscribe to each derived type, which isn't ideal in my usage scenario.  Any idea why the auto-subscribe doesn't work for this one?

Comment: No, I don't know why it doesn't work. But you could do the auto-subscribe yourself, something like https://gist.github.com/905204